# Proof of this infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove this statement when $\text{q}>0$ and $t\ge0$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\text{H}\left(t-\frac{qn}{2}\right)e^{-\frac{\left(t-\frac{qn}{2}\right)}{p}}=\frac{e^{-\frac{t}{p}}\left(e^{\frac{q\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{2t}{q}\right\rfloor\right)}{2p}}-1\right)}{e^{\frac{q}{2p}}-1}$$

A less attractive but also less compressed version, more suitable for tired eyes:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty H\left(t-\frac{qn}2\right)\exp\left(-\frac1p\left(t-\frac{qn}2\right)\right)=\frac{e^{-t/p}\left(\exp\left[\frac{q}{2p}\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac{2t}q\right\rfloor\right)\right]-1\right)}{\exp\left(\frac{q}{2p}\right)-1}$$

$\text{H}(x)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: You should probably specify what convention you are using for the Heaviside function (i.e., what happens at zero?). If I am allowed to stand on a soap box for a second, this ambiguity is why we should reserve the use of $H$ for distributional work and use (explicitly defined) indicator functions otherwise.

Comment: It's actually a finite sum, due to the Heaviside function. It's a geometric sum.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this question is meant for answering or just for admiring!

The $e^{-\frac{t}{p}}$ is just a common factor. The effect of the Heaviside function is to make it a finite sum. So if we put $\lambda=e^{\frac{q}{2p}}$ the basic problem is just finding $\sum_{n=0}^N\lambda^n$. That, of course, is just a geometric series with sum $\frac{\lambda^{N+1}-1}{\lambda-1}$.

The slightly tricky part is $N$. If $\frac{2t}{q}$ is not an integer, then we just have $N=\lfloor{\frac{2t}{q}}\rfloor$. Sometimes, at least $H[0]=\frac{1}{2}$. Here apparently it is 0. So our final answer is just $e^{\frac{t}{p}}\frac{\lambda^{N+1}-1}{\lambda-1}$. Writing that out in full $$e^{-\frac{t}{p}}\frac{e^{\frac{q}{2p}(1+\lfloor{\frac{2t}{q}}\rfloor)}-1}{e^{\frac{q}{2p}}-1}$$